# Confirmation button, triggers all confirmation boxes to open

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am in the process of finishing my todo application, since redux is a bit new to me of course I encounter problems. My problem is when I click the delete button (recycle icon) I want a confirmation box to pop up with basic Yes and No buttons, I have built that, but... when I click one recycle button all of the other confirmation boxes get set to True and they pop up in sync. I need only one box to pop up for the right todo.id.

Note: I have built this before without redux, but I am still wrapping my head around redux.

Here is my code:

JS:

```
import React, {useState, Fragment} from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import "./todo.css"

const Todos = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const todos = useSelector(state => state.todos);
const confirmationSt = useSelector(state => state.confirmation)
const handleConfirm = id => {
    dispatch({
        type: "CONFIRM",  
    })
}
const handleContinue = () => {
    dispatch({
        type: "CONTINUE",
        
    })
}
const handleClick = id => dispatch({
    type: "DELETE_TODO",
    payload: id,
})
if (!todos || !todos.length) {
    return <p>Empty</p>
}

return (
    <ul className='unlist'>{todos.map(todo =><Fragment key={todo.id}> <div  className='todoContent'><li >{todo.label}</li>
     <div><button className='delete' onClick={handleConfirm}><i className="fas fa-recycle"></i></button> 
     <button className='delete' onClick={handleConfirm}><i className="fas fa-wrench"></i></button> 
     </div> 
    
     </div>
     {confirmationSt === true ? <div className='confirmation-box'>
         Are you sure?
         <button  onClick={() => handleClick(todo.id)}>Yes</button>
         <button onClick={handleContinue}>No</button>
     </div> : null}
     </Fragment>
      )}
     
     </ul>
)   
}
```

Reducer:

```
const initalState = {
todos: [],
confirmation: false,

}

const reducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
        return {
            ...state,
            todos: [...state.todos, action.payload],
            
        }
    case "DELETE_TODO":
        return {
            ...state,
            todos: state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload)
        }
    case "CONFIRM":
        return {
            ...state,
            confirmation: !state.confirmation,
        }
    case "CONTINUE":
        return {
            ...state,
            confirmation: false
        }
        default: return state;
 }
}

export default reducer
```

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to make each todo item its own component and then use local state (React.useState) instead of Redux for the `confirmationSt` boolean. If you really want to store it in Redux, you will need to do more work, for instance storing an array of booleans or the ID of the current todo. It would be much easier to have it as local state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed confirmation from boolean to id of the task

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import "./todo.css"

const Todos = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const todos = useSelector(state => state.todos);
  const confirmationSt = useSelector(state => state.confirmation)
  const handleConfirm = id => {
    dispatch({
      type: "CONFIRM",
      payload: id
    })
  }
  const handleContinue = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "CONTINUE",
    })
  }
  const handleClick = id => dispatch({
    type: "DELETE_TODO",
    payload: id,
  })
  if (!todos || !todos.length) {
    return <p>Empty</p>
  }

  return (
    <ul className='unlist'>
      { todos.map(todo => 
          <Fragment key={todo.id}> 
              <div className='todoContent'>
                  <li >{todo.label}</li>
                  <div>
                    <button className='delete' onClick={()=>handleConfirm(todo.id)}>
                      <i className="fas fa-recycle"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button className='delete' onClick={()=>handleConfirm(todo.id)}>
                      <i className="fas fa-wrench"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
              </div>
              {
                confirmationSt === todo.id ? 
                <div className='confirmation-box'>
                    Are you sure?
                    <button onClick={() => handleClick(todo.id)}>Yes</button>
                    <button onClick={handleContinue}>No</button>
                </div> 
                : null
              }
          </Fragment>
    )}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

```
const initalState = {
todos: [],
confirmation: -1,

}

const reducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
        return {
            ...state,
            todos: [...state.todos, action.payload],
            
        }
    case "DELETE_TODO":
        return {
            ...state,
            todos: state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload)
        }
    case "CONFIRM":
        return {
            ...state,
            confirmation: action.payload,
        }
    case "CONTINUE":
        return {
            ...state,
            confirmation: false
        }
        default: return state;
 }
}

export default reducer
```